# How to check if ArangoDB query is not empty?

Tags: arangodb, aql

I would like to make an `exists` PostgreSQL query.

Let's say I have a `Q` ArangoDB query (AQL). How can I check if Q returns any result?

Example:

```
Q = "For u in users FILTER 'x@example.com' = u.email"
```

## What is the best way to do it (most performant)?

I have ideas, but couldn't find an easy way to measure the performance:

### Idea 1: using `Length`:

```
RETURN LENGTH(%Q RETURN 1) > 0
```

### Idea 2: using `Frist`:

```
RETURN First(%Q RETURN 1) != null
```

Above, `%Q` is a substitution for the query defined at the beginning.

Comment: Try this:
`LET Q = (FOR u IN users FILTER @email == u.email))`
`RETURN { email_found: LENGTH(Q) > 0 ? true : false }`
And send the param @email containing the email to search for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to achieve this for a generic selection query with a structure like

> Q = "For u in users FILTER 'x@example.com' = u.email"

is to first add a LIMIT clause to the query, and only make it return a constant value (in contrast to the full document).

For example, the following query returns a single match if there is such document or an empty array if there is no match:

```
FOR u IN users FILTER 'x@example.com' == u.email LIMIT 1 RETURN 1
```

(please note that I also changed the operator from `=` to `==` because otherwise the query won't parse).

Please note that this query may benefit a lot from creating an index on the search attribute, i.e. `email`. Without the index the query will do a full collection scan and stop at the first match, whereas with the index it will just read at most a single index entry.

Finally, to answer your question, the template for the `EXISTS`-like query will then become

```
LENGTH(%Q LIMIT 1 RETURN 1)
```

or fleshed out via the example query:

```
LENGTH(FOR u IN users FILTER 'x@example.com' == u.email LIMIT 1 RETURN 1)
```

`LENGTH(...)` will return the number of matches, which in this case will either be 0 or 1. And it can also be used in filter conditions like as follows

```
FOR ....
  FILTER LENGTH(...)
  RETURN ...
```

because `LENGTH(...)` will be either 0 or 1, which in context of a FILTER condition will evaluate to either false or true.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need and AQL solution?

Only the count:

```
var q  = "For u in users FILTER 'x@example.com' = u.email";
var res = db._createStatement({query: q, count: true}).execute();
var ct = res.count();
```

Is the fastest I can think of.